# Text in Spinner overlapping with custom background of Spinner Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with custom background . Know I can load the data in spinner but when I select the item of spinner and if the text is lengthy then it is overlapping or cutting the background image of spinner. I searched on the internet but did not found solution . Here is my code and the screenshot of the result. !
[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXKTK.png)
[image: Actual background Image(dropdown_button)]

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

**Edit after giving padding:**

After giving right padding I am getting text not overlapping or cutting image.[image: Screenshot of the result]

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" /> //Here
```

Comment: change the spinner `layout_width` or reduce `textSize`

Comment: I also face this problem in past... and what i have do is that, i just set 2 dots at the end of String if the data string is too much lengthy.

Comment: The problem is I have a requirement not to set the spinner width to wrap_content. And second if I reduce the spinner text size more then it would not be readable.

Comment: @User42590 please double check your Background image should name like this name_of_file.9.png  note the (.9.png) at the end of file name

Comment: Also try to add Padding in your spinner, and the spinner Item's Layout

Comment: @QadirHussain image is nine patch that why it is with extension .9.png. And second is yes I tried the right padding android:paddingRight="20dp" and it is working fine.

Comment: @User42590 I have posted as answer. please accept this If this helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add Padding in your spinner like this

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" /> //Padding Right
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you are fixing the width of the spinner so thats why you text is not properly showing :

```html
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: The problem is I have a requirement not to set the spinner width to wrap_content.

Comment: open the spinner on a textview click that has fixed width